# Is there a way to keep bluetooth headphone from going into power-saving mode?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones

I have a number of bluetooth headphones, and when they are connected to OSX, I notice some annoying phenomena. That phenomena is, when I do not play audio, the bluetooth headphones will quickly go into power-saving mode. And when I resume the audio, it will have a tiny explosion sound and then it will skip a second of audio. This is particularly annoying when I am working on music tracks. Can we disable the power-saving on bluetooth headphones or find a way to prevent it from going into power-saving mode? (Like looping a very silent sound in the background...)

Comment: The Sleep mode is initiated by the Bluetooth it self to preserve its battery. Check with your BT manufacture for documentation if it is possible to turn it off or extend.